# syminfo.mintick on TradingView's Strategy Tester

Tags: c#, pine-script

I was analyzing TradingView's Strategy Tester and I [found out](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Mc2wPUg2-Pinescript-v4-The-Holy-Grail-Trailing-Stop/) about their trailing stop loss bug. Basically, the bug makes you almost never lose, because it takes the `High` value. That's exactly how I simulate it in my C# code and I'm getting the same unrealistic results due to that reason.

A guy on the [comments](https://www.tradingview.com/script/Mc2wPUg2-Pinescript-v4-The-Holy-Grail-Trailing-Stop/) said:

> convert price into ticks you can do it like this: trail_points = value / syminfo.mintick

How exactly is `syminfo.mintick` being calculated on TradingView? I'm trying to figure it out how it actually works. Put the focus on what's below.

```
trailOffsetPerc = input(title="Trailing-Stop Offset (%)", type=input.float, minval=1, maxval=100, step=0.5, defval=5) * 0.01
trailPointsPerc = input(title="Trailing-Stop Points (%)", type=input.float, minval=1, maxval=100, step=0.5, defval=2) * 0.01

...

strategy.exit("SellTrailSL", "Buy", trail_points=close * trailPointsPerc / syminfo.mintick, trail_offset=close * trailOffsetPerc / syminfo.mintick, comment="Trailing-Stop")
```

How is that possible that their Strategy Tester produces same results as on live trading? They don't use tick data, how is that possible without it?

Comment: I'm interested in this but not completely sure what you are asking. A tick is the minimum price a stock can move. $.01 for stocks valued over a dollar. So different commodities have different tick sizes, like S&P E-minis are $0.25 I believe, currency pairs are 'pips', etc. Regarding how a trailing stop works live I would check your broker's documentation. If you are selling based on your own signals generating sales with your broker you should be able to implement a trailing stop however you want as long as it makes sense.

Comment: @bajaco, seems like `syminfo.mintick` is something like 0.01, however I would like to know if there is a documentation on how their trailing stop loss works.

Comment: I was looking for some info and stumbled across this: https://backtest-rookies.com/2018/06/08/tradingview-trailing-stop-mechanics-beware-version-3/ Reminded me of this post. This may be a separate issue from what you are asking, but it speaks of the trailing stop being inaccurate because of the broker emulator making assumptions about low being hit first on a green bar and vice versa.

Comment: @bajaco, thank you for that article! It is for version 3 and things may have changed in v4. I admit what they said about "Tradingview always assumes that price moved in your favour first during a bar". That's the reason I always test my strategies on finished candles only. More precisely, these two "Recalculate" options are always disabled https://i.imgur.com/d4zjNCa.png

Comment: @bajaco, let's say that we hit static stop loss and profit target in a same candle. My own backtesting in C# assumes that the stop loss was triggered first, because it's the worst condition between the two. The actual problem is with the trailing stop loss, that it cannot be backtested correctly, because you assume that it takes *High* value of the candle, which creates some positive expectation, which doesn't really happen in real time, as I've tested for almost 2 years.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I thought that might actually be part of the issue with the trailing stop loss as it would not account for the trailing stop to be set by the high of the candle then closed by intrabar movement even when the final close would not have triggered it.